# AutoML H2O gives multinomial result instead of binomial

Tags: python, h2o, automl, multinomial

I am trying to proccess the dataset [kr-vs-kp](https://www.openml.org/search?type=data&sort=runs&id=3&status=active) using AutoML H2O. The dataset has two possible target values "nowin" and "win", so I suppose it should be binary classification. But after the model is found it turns out that H2O regarded it as a multiclass classification problem (accuracy score is absent, and confusion matrix is present).
Why does that happend, and what I have to fix so that it will be binary classification problem?

The code to run AutoML is as follow:

```
info = h2o.import_file("kr-vs-kp.csv")
train,test = info.split_frame(ratios=[.75])

x = train.columns
y = x.pop()

train[y] = train[y].asfactor() #doesn't change anything
test[y] = test[y].asfactor()   #doesn't change anything

automl = h2o.automl.H2OAutoML(max_runtime_secs=900)

automl.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

perf = automl.leader.model_performance(test)

print("perf type:", type(perf))

print("Algorithm", automl.leader.show())

print("Confusion Matrix", perf.confusion_matrix())
print("Accuracy score", perf.accuracy())
```

The output is as follow:

```
perf type: <class 'h2o.model.metrics.multinomial.H2OMultinomialModelMetrics'>

Algorithm GBM_1_AutoML_1_20230217_142818

Confusion Matrix Confusion Matrix: Row labels: Actual class; Column labels: Predicted class
class   nowin   won Error   Rate
-------  -------  -----  ---------  --------
0       0       0   nan     0 / 0
0       341     14  0.0394366  14 / 355
0       16      402 0.0382775  16 / 418
0       357     416 0.0388098  30 / 773

AttributeError: type object 'MetricsBase' has no attribute 'accuracy'
```

Upd. OK, It seems that I have found the source of the problem. For some strange reason the first line in the file is regarded not as columns' names, but as data, so target has three values: win, nowin, class. But why? All other files that I tried so far were processed normally with first line being columns' names.

First line in file, with columns' names:

```
bkblk,bknwy,bkon8,bkona,bkspr,bkxbq,bkxcr,bkxwp,blxwp,bxqsq,cntxt,dsopp,dwipd,hdchk,katri,mulch,qxmsq,r2ar8,reskd,reskr,rimmx,rkxwp,rxmsq,simpl,skach,skewr,skrxp,spcop,stlmt,thrsk,wkcti,wkna8,wknck,wkovl,wkpos,wtoeg,class
```

Comment: This is because you are importing your file as ndarray or something other than dataframe so it would not understand that this is just a label. Instead, try to import as df and then transform it. I always do this since it is way easier to prevent such errors.